# Counter Speeds Up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why this script causes the counter to speed up each time 'start' is clicked. What do i need to insert to keep this from happening?

```
var count = 1;
var counting = function () {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        $('#numbers').html(count);
        count++;
    }, 1000);
    function counting() {};
}
$("#start").click(counting);
$('#stop').click(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
$('#reset').click(function () {
    count = 0;
    $('#numbers').html(count);
});
```

Comment: Unless you clear the existing interval, you are creating a new interval each time you click start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because every time 'Start' is clicked, it calls the function which creates an interval. Calling the setInterval function again does not stop the previous interval.

A quick solution would be to call `clearInterval( timer )` before `setInterval(...)`, like so :

```
var timer;
var counting = function() {
    clearInterval( timer );
    timer = setInterval( function() {
        $('#numbers').html( count );
        count++;
    }, 1000 );
}
```

Notice that I declared `timer` beforehand because clicking 'Start' the first time would generate an error saying something like `timer is undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to match `setInterval` with `clearInterval`, not `clearTimeout`.

You also need to prevent additional calls to `counting` if the timer is already started, e.g. by putting a `$('#start').prop('disabled', true)` call inside `counting`.

Alternatively, just ensure that you call `clearInterval(timer)` immediately before you call `timer = setInterval(...)`